# How to use to_regclass with uppercase table names?

Tags: postgresql

I am using `to_regclass()` to check if a table exists (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/476074)). This works for lowercase table names, but for table names with capital letters it always returns NULL, even when the table exists:

```
CREATE TABLE "asdf" (s text);
CREATE TABLE "FooBar" (s text);

SELECT to_regclass('asdf'); --     -> "asdf"
SELECT to_regclass('FooBar'); --   -> NULL
SELECT to_regclass('foobar'); --   -> NULL
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/756fb/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start using those dreaded double quotes, you have to use them **always**:

```
SELECT to_regclass('"FooBar"');
```

<sup>(another good example why you should avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers)</sup>